# Should I use `new` when calling functions that return the same object whether or not called as constructor?

Tags: javascript, performance, new-operator

Some functions that return the same object whether or not called as constructor.

In terms of performance, should I use

`new RegExp(rg, flags);`

`new Array(1000);`

<del>`new Object(whatever);`</del>

`...`

or

`RegExp(rg, flags);`

`Array(1000);`

<del>`Object(whatever);`</del>

`...`

?

**Edit**: I was wrong, it matters if I use `Object()` or `new Object()`

Comment: That title is pretty different from the question. Why not just run some tests on [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/)? To really answer this, you'll need to specify which browsers and constructors you care about. My hunch is that it doesn't have a major impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type. For `Array` it is equivalent:

> When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new `Array` object. Thus the function call `Array(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(…)` with the same arguments.

For `Object`:

> When `Object` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.
>   When `Object` is called as part of a `new` expression, it is a constructor that may create an object.

You can look up other types in the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was wrong with `Object`/`new Object`. But what about the performance in cases it's the same (e.g `Array`/`new Array`)?

Comment: @Oriol No difference.

Comment: @Oriol Wait, actually [using `new` is much faster, by a surprising amount: 97%!](http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-array-with-items) Of course an array literal is the fastest.

Comment: Amazing difference! But I have just tested it on FF 23 and all three options had the same performance. I have created [another jsperf](http://jsperf.com/calling-array-as-constructor-vs-as-function) with only size argument, and more or less the same: on Chrome it's better without `new` when the size is little

Answer (score 0):

> In terms of performance

In terms of performance, use literals wherever possible

```
// Array
var arr = [0, 2, 4];

// Object
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};

// RegExp
var re = /foo/ig;
```

perf for [*Array*](http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-literal/15), perf for [*Object*](http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-constructor-vs-object-literal/86), perf for [*RegExp*](http://jsperf.com/regexp-literal-vs-regexp-constructor-vs-new-regexp-cons/3).

Comment: But in some cases literals can't be used, e.g., using a variable inside a regular expression. Then, should I use `new` or not?

Comment: @Oriol for variables inside a _regular expression_ you would need to use `new` to avoid bad practices (such as `eval`), yes.

Comment: But I can use `RegExp(myvar,myflag)` (no `new`) without using `eval`